# how to write the members of structure to a file?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[124];
    int age;
    int class;
} student;

main( ) {
    student s1;
    int fd = -1;
    int fh = creat( "student.db", O_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
    fd = open( "student.db", O_RDWR | O_APPEND );
    if ( fd<0 ) {
        perror( "failed to create student file:" );
        return;
    }
    s1.age = 15;
    s1.class = 9;
    strcpy( s1.name, "John" );
    int ret = write( fd, &s1, sizeof( student ) );
    printf( "ret of write: %d \n", ret );
    system( "gvim student.db" );
}
```

I am trying to write a record to a file. Since structure contains integer elements only name is written successfully, whereas the int elements are displayed as garbage. Could anyone please have a look at the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That "garbage" is your data, just not in human-readable format.

Comment: Thanks. How can I confirm whether the record is inserted?

Comment: Read it back into your struct and check that it’s correct.

Comment: If I would like to read the record from the file, how may I  do so?

Comment: With `read(fd, &s1, sizeof s1)`, just as you've written them. :)

Comment: .. and lseek - http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek

Comment: I really appreciate that mafso

Comment: I think only strings can be written to a file. If one of the elements in the struct is an INT, will it writes to the file?

Comment: @user3770743 - You can write any binary data to a file. Applications are binary data (for example)

Comment: I have got the answer. Since struct contains integer elements and when we try to write the int to a file. We can't read the content as it is converted to ascii form internally. But we can always read the record and view the members in a record like mafso said above

Answer (score 1):

Using a command like `od -x` you can get a hex dump of file contents useful for debugging.
You'ld make it easier for yourself if you reorder the structure members, so the integers are first.

An example, showing a file with count of 64bit fibonacci sequence from 0.. :

```
ladm@ash:~/src/fib/fibs_tab> od -x < fib_uint64| head
0000000 005e 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0001 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0002 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000 0000 0000
0000060 0005 0000 0000 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000
0000100 000d 0000 0000 0000 0015 0000 0000 0000
0000120 0022 0000 0000 0000 0037 0000 0000 0000
0000140 0059 0000 0000 0000 0090 0000 0000 0000
0000160 00e9 0000 0000 0000 0179 0000 0000 0000
0000200 0262 0000 0000 0000 03db 0000 0000 0000
0000220 063d 0000 0000 0000 0a18 0000 0000 0000
```

First integer is a count 0x5e (93), followed by 3 empty higher significant bytes, then sequence begins.  0,1,1,2,3,5 and so on.